# "en une journée" or "dans une journée"

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-temps

"There were three explosions in one day."

> Il y a eu trois explosions ___ une journée.

Should we use *en* or *dans*, or do both work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With *une journée* (one day), ***en*** is expected:

> *Il y a eu trois explosion **en** une journée.* (… in one day)

***En*** is used here to specify the amount of time that was necessary for the three events to occur.

However, if the last part of the sentence had been ***la** journée*, ***dans*** would have been used:

> *Il y a eu trois explosions **dans** la journée.* (… during the day/through the day)

***Dans*** means here "inside", not inside a given space which is the main acception for ***dans*** but inside a given period of time.

See the very same difference in these sentences:

> *La petite aiguille fait 24 fois le tour du cadran **en** une journée.*

The minute hand makes 24 turns of the dial **in one day**.

> *Il y a 24 heures **dans** une journée.*

There are 24 hours **in one day**.

Similarily:

> *Il y a eu trois explosions **en** vingt-quatre heures.* (… during a period of 24 hours)
>
> *Il y a eu trois explosions **dans** la même journée.* (… in a single day)

---

Note that *dans* can also be used to tell the time that will elapse before some event occur:

> ***Dans** trois jours, on vide la piscine.*

Three days from now, we'll empty the swimming pool.

> ***En** trois jours, on vide la piscine.*

To empty the swimming-pool, we need/take three days.

Comment: *Il y a 24 heures dans une journée.* *Dans 3 jours on part à la plage.* Ce serait bien d'expliquer ces cas-là aussi !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est fait, enfin j'espère…

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is : `en`

Il y a eu trois explosions **en** une journée.

Answer (score -1):

It should be : en

Not : dans

For dates we uses : en

Example : en 1992 not dans 1992