# « En quatre ans » ou « dans quatre ans »

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-temps

> Il a fini ses études **en** quatre ans.

ou

> Il a fini ses études **dans** quatre ans.

Dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22802/11550), on a dit qu'on utilise « en une journée » mais « dans la journée ». Si on suit cette règle, on devrait utiliser « en quatre ans ». Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le problème avec

> Il a fini ses études **dans** quatre ans

est l'incohérence entre le passé composé ***a fini*** qui indique<sup>1</sup> que l'action est terminée et ***dans quatre ans*** qui ne peut signifier qu'une échéance future.

Il est donc recommandé d'écrire :

> Il a fini ses études **en** quatre ans.

Ses études sont achevées et elles ont duré quatre ans.

Avec le verbe au futur antérieur (temps composé), les deux variantes sont possibles

> *Il **aura** fini ses études **en** quatre ans*
>
> *il **aura** fini ses études **dans** quatre ans*

Dans le premier cas, la durée totale des études est de quatre ans mais on ne sait pas quand elles seront terminées alors que dans le deuxième cas, quatre ans est la durée qu'il reste avant l'achèvement des études mais leur durée totale est peut-être supérieure à quatre ans.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>En français parlé, le passé composé peut être aussi utilisé pour exprimer un fait «certain» situé dans le futur, exemple «j'ai fini dans cinq minutes !»</sub>

Comment: *Il a fini ses études dans 4 ans* peut être correct. Cela peut être un usage (pas courant, certes) du passé composé pour un fait futur qui, au moment présent, est si sûr d'être accompli qu'on le met au participe passé. Exemple: *Viens me chercher après le travail. J'ai fini à 18 heures*

Comment: @Greg C'est vrai. En français parlé, le passé composé peut être utilisé de cette façon et c'est même assez courant (ex: *J'ai fini dans une heure !*)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that dans 4 ans clashes with the use of past tense (even though, yes we can use it in spoken French).

I still want to pinpoint that if we ignore these details, here "en" and "dans" represent two different things.

`Il a fini ses études en 4 ans` is an interval of time. It took him 4 years to finish his studies.

`Il a fini ses études dans 4 ans` is a fixed point on time. It represents a single moment.